# Multiple Image Upload: Progress bar for each upload

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I need different progress bars for each image upload for my Angular4 application. (Storing with AngularFireStore)

**My component**

```
percentageArray = [];

startUpload(event: FileList) {

 Array.from(event).forEach(file => {
   if (file.type.split('/')[0] != 'image') {
     alert('Dieses Dateiformat wird nicht unterstützt');
   }

   // Storage path
  const path = `uploads/${this.currentUserEmail}/${this.uniqueID}/${file.name}`;

  // Meta Data
  const customMetadata = {
    auctionID: this.uniqueID.toString()
  }

   // Main Task
  this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, {customMetadata});

  // Progress Monitoring

  this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
  this.percentage.subscribe(p => {
    this.percentageArray.push(p);
  })

  this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();

  // File Download Url
  this.downloadURL = this.task.downloadURL();

  this.imgArray.push(path);

 })
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="percentageArray as item" class="w-100">
  <div *ngFor="let elem of item">
  <ngb-progressbar type="info" [value]="elem" [striped]="true" [max]="100" [showValue]="true"></ngb-progressbar>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Result**
[image: I uploaded only 2 images]

For each status I get a new progress bar...how I can force to combine it in only one for each upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use index of current file.

```
startUpload(event: FileList) {  Array.from(event).forEach((file, index) => { // <-- separate index for each file
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] != 'image') {
      alert('Dieses Dateiformat wird nicht unterstützt');
    }

    // Storage path
    const path = `uploads/${this.currentUserEmail}/${this.uniqueID}/${file.name}`;

// Meta Data
const customMetadata = {
  auctionID: this.uniqueID.toString()
}

// Main Task
this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, {customMetadata});

// Progress Monitoring

this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
this.percentage.subscribe(p => {
  this.percentageArray[index] = p; // <--- just put new percentage to needed index
})

this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();

// File Download Url
this.downloadURL = this.task.downloadURL();

this.imgArray.push(path);})}
```

Then remove one loop from html

```
<div *ngIf="percentageArray as item" class="w-100"> 
<ngb-progressbar type="info" [value]="item" [striped]="true"
[max]="100" showValue]="true"></ngb-progressbar></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be an array (maybe an array with keys and values, but then the update is more complicated).

e.g.

```
percentageArray = {};
```

```
this.percentage.subscribe(p => {
    // Update percentage for this file.
    this.percentageArray[file.name] = p;
});
```

Not sure how to best iterate over object keys/values in Angular HTML, but you probably can find the answer to that somewhere on SO.

Comment: Thanks. But with this solution I get the following error in my loop: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: @eleinad: That is why i noted that you have to find a different method for iterating over the object property values. As noted you could also use an array with e.g. a `key` and `value` property, then you can iterate it again, but you need to find the item with the right `key` for updates. Alternatively you could just use the file's index for lookup.

Comment: Just as i wrote that, i saw that Vayrex submitted an answer that simply uses the index, which should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :) The solution above works fine :)